# orchard cms content part, field gets added twice and can't remove

Tags: c#, asp.net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I added a simple field to a content part

```
ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition("CarouselContentPart", b =>
            b
            .WithField("AutoPlay", cfg =>
                cfg.OfType("NumericField")
                    .WithSetting("NumericFieldSettings.Hint", "Enter a value in milliseconds for autoplay (leave blank for no autoplay)")
                    .WithSetting("NumericFieldSettings.Required", "false")
                    .WithDisplayName("Autoplay"))
            );

        return 18;
```

its got added twice and now I can't remove it, either through another migration or through the back office. this is the stack trace

> An unhandled exception has occurred and the request was terminated. Please refresh the page. If the error persists, go back
>   Sequence contains more than one matching element
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate) at Orchard.ContentManagement.MetaData.Builders.ContentPartDefinitionBuilder.RemoveField(String fieldName) in C:\Development\FE-Corporate\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\MetaData\Builders\ContentPartDefinitionBuilder.cs:line 46 at Orchard.ContentTypes.Services.ContentDefinitionService.<>c__DisplayClass48.b__47(ContentPartDefinitionBuilder typeBuilder) at Orchard.ContentManagement.MetaData.ContentDefinitionManagerExtensions.AlterPartDefinition(IContentDefinitionManager manager, String name, Action`1 alteration) in C:\Development\FE-Corporate\src\Orchard\ContentManagement\MetaData\IContentDefinitionManager.cs:line 32 at Orchard.ContentTypes.Services.ContentDefinitionService.RemoveFieldFromPart(String fieldName, String partName) at Orchard.ContentTypes.Controllers.AdminController.RemoveFieldFromPOST(String id) at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()

Comment: Looks like the code expects only one field and can't work with multiple. I guess your only option is to remove some records from the database where the fields are attached

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any important data in your new content part yet you can try just dropping and recreating it with a migration.

This will make you lose all the data saved for the content part but will also give you a chance to make a clean break.

You can remove the content part like this:

```
    public int UpdateFrom18() {
        // remove the CarouselContentPart part cleanly
        ContentDefinitionManager.DeletePartDefinition(typeof (CarouselContentPart).Name);
enter code here
        // re-add the CarouselContentPart again
        // NOTE: Change this bit to add include whatever you have created in your previous 17 migrations such as setting up the part and adding fields
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(typeof (CarouselContentPart).Name,
            cfg = > cfg
            .Attachable()
            .WithDescription("Some kind of description, etc"));
        return 4;
    }
```